# Wordpress Social Locker locks content even if user already liked page

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed OnePress Social Blocker plugin to my Wordpress website.

I set up everything correctly according to documentation. When user likes Facebook page, content is shown. But right after I refresh my page content is blocked again and user must click on Unlike button and then click again on Like button to reveal content, which is not very user friendly.

The problem is simply, that plugin doesn't remember click on Like button. According to plugin documentation it should remember browser and PC, but it doesn't. Any advice to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use the version 3.0.0. Please update to the version 3.0.2.

Paul